# XSLTProcessor issues

Tags: php, xslt

I have the following XML for my XSLT stylesheet (take note of the `table-number` parameter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tet="http://www.pdflib.com/XML/TET3/TET-3.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:param name="table-number" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="page-number" select="0" />
    <xsl:param name="separator-char" select="','" />
    <xsl:variable name="double-quote">"</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test="tet:TET/tet:Document/tet:Pages/tet:Page/tet:Content[not(@granularity = 'word' or @granularity = 'page')]">
            <xsl:message terminate="yes">
                <xsl:text>Stylesheet table.xsl processing TETML for document '</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="tet:TET/tet:Document/@filename" />
                <xsl:text>': this stylesheet requires word info in TETML.</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>Create the input in page mode "word" or "wordplus".</xsl:text>
            </xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$page-number = 0">
                <xsl:variable name="table" select="(tet:TET/tet:Document/tet:Pages/tet:Page//tet:Table)[$table-number]"/>
                <xsl:if test="count($table) = 0">
                    <xsl:call-template name="table-not-found" />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$table" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="table" select="(tet:TET/tet:Document/tet:Pages/tet:Page[@number = $page-number]//tet:Table)[$table-number]"/>
                <xsl:if test="count($table) = 0">
                    <xsl:call-template name="table-not-found" />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$table" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    .
    .
    .
</stylesheet>
```

And the following PHP code executes the XSLT on a given input file of XML:

```
protected function tetml_to_csv() {
    $processor = new XSLTProcessor();

    $xsl = new DOMDocument();
    $xsl->load(realpath('./path/to/xslt/tetml_to_csv.xsl'), LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    $processor->importStylesheet($xsl);

    $tetml = file_get_contents($this->tetmlDoc);

    $tetml = new DOMDocument();
    $tetml->load($this->tetmlDoc);

    //var_dump($processor->getParameter('xsl', 'table-number'));
    //exit();
    $processor->setParameter(NULL, 'table-number', 1);

    file_put_contents($this->filepath . 'output.csv',  $processor->transformToXml($tetml));

    unlink($this->tetmlDoc);
}
```

When I run the code without calling `setParameter()` the XSLT places only the first table from the input XML into the output .csv file (which is the expected behavior).

However, when I call `setParameter()` prior to executing the conversion, **ALL** tables from the input XML file are transferred to the output .csv file, even if I set the value of the parameter to the default value.

When I call `getParameter()` the function returns `false` (even though the return value is supposed to be either the value of the parameter, or `null` if the parameter isn't found).

I tried changing the value for `namespace` that I pass to the functions, but that didn't help at all.

What am I doing wrong? It must be something simple, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

**EDIT**

I have tried passing the `value` parameter for `setParameter()` as both a string and a numeric; both had the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t know the API but http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php suggests the argument passed in by PHP is a string so perhaps when you do `$processor->setParameter(NULL, 'table-number', 1);` the number `1` is passed as a string to XSLT and in that case the positional predicates in XSLT don't work unless you explicitly write them as `[position() = $table-number]`.

Comment: I tried passing a string as well; same outcome. The XSLT is from the PDFLib TET cookbook, and is functioning correctly; the issue is with PHP's `setParameter()` function from what I can gather. Do you think it could it be the `namespace`?

Comment: You need to change the XSLT as I suggested. If PHP passes in parameters as strings your XSLT code `foo[$table-number]` is evaluated as `foo["1"]` and that is selecting all `foo` elements. So write the positional predicates as `foo[position() = $table-number]` or as `foo[number($table-number)]`.